# Mesh from a curve using Bevel Object gets flat when exporting to Unity

Tags: mesh, export, unity, bevel

In blender, I made a hair bow using Bevel Object on a curve. Afterwards I converted the curve into a mesh but regardless wich polygon resolution I choose, the exported fbx object doesn't look voluminous at all in Unity. It is therefore not possible to put the hair bow on top of a head, as too much of the head's surface underneath is visible. I dont`t understand the reason behind this, so I am a bit stuck now. (Added 2 screenshots of both objects)

[image: Blender model]
[image: Unity Object]

Comment: I would start by checking the normals.  I wouldn't expect that to be the issue coming from a beveled curve but that's what the Unity screenshot looks like to me.  Try recalculating normals on the mesh before exporting.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. First forgot to mark all faces in edit mode before recalculating the normals, but finally that solves the problem.